# Intel Core i5-2467M running hot on one core while the other keeps cool

Tags: 11.10, intel, cpu, temperature

I am running an Ubuntu 11.10 Beta2 Wubi installation on my Samsung 900x3a notebook. I had to try it with wubi because this darn thing just won't boot off usb drives (even using the port on the right side). But this is another story.

First thing I noticed was that the fan doesn't go into an idle state. It's always spinning on full power. The System Monitor shows an evenly distributed usage of all 4 virtual cores.

But what is actually looking very suspiciously to me is the output of `lm-sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +62.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

As you can see, it seems like one core is not getting enough air. Or to name another possibility maybe one core isn't (fully) used by the system?

On Windows 7 I usually get around 55° C to 68° C (only when the CPU usage is near 100 %).

Does anyone have similar problems or maybe even a solution to get the temperatures leveled and therefore to get the fan go idle?

[cat /proc/cpuinfo](http://pastebin.com/tR631BAt)

Comment: That's essentially impossible. The cores are too tiny to have such drastically different temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same confusion going on. The sensors command does not print the two core temperatures. The temperatures it showed are #1 the two cpu cores together and #2 the hdd.

I stumbled upon [the samsung-tools project](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa). After I installed the package I was able to silent my fan by running

```
samsung-tools --cpu silent
```

It's all quiet now. Hope it helps.

Comment: The 'temp1' value is the temperature at the inside of the heat spreader. It's a more accurate temperature measuring device than the cores themselves provide, but there is only one of them in the CPU package.

Comment: David Schwartz : The 'temp1' temperature isn't accurate on this model. Or my 900x3a always run with a processor temp above 70°C ... I thinks there is realy a problem with temp monitoring, and before 11.10 I use 11.04 and temp monitoring was correct.